# set yarn registry settings with CLI

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, .npmrc

I have an `.npmrc` file with the following settings:

```
@mms:registry=https://artifactory.local/artifactory/api/npm/npm-dp-local/
//artifactory.local/artifactory/api/npm/npm-dp-local/:_auth = ${ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN}
//artifactory.local/artifactory/api/npm/npm-dp-local/:email = ${ARTIFACTORY_EMAIL}
//artifactory.local/artifactory/api/npm/npm-dp-local/:always-auth = true
```

I need to set those configuration params with cli.
Setting registry is pretty straightforward:

```bash
yarn config set @mms:registry=https://artifactory.local/artifactory/api/npm/npm-dp-local/
```

But how do I set the authentication params related to the registry?

I tried:

```bash
yarn config set //artifactory.local/artifactory/api/npm/npm-dp-local/:_auth $ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN
yarn config set //artifactory.local/artifactory/api/npm/npm-dp-local/:email $ARTIFACTORY_EMAIL
yarn config set //artifactory.local/artifactory/api/npm/npm-dp-local/:always-auth true
```

and

```bash
yarn config set _auth $ARTIFACTORY_TOKEN
yarn config set email $ARTIFACTORY_EMAIL
yarn config set always-auth true
```

And getting 401 Unauthorized in response from the registry.

But with the .npmrc file everything works fine.

How do I correctly set those params with CLI?